# iPhone + In App purchase testing

Tags: iphone, testing

I have implemented In App purchase in one of the existing application. I have also created SandBox account for testing it. I have run the application and tested it, its working perfect. Since, I have tested it, by buying the feature, it means I have bought that feature.

Now, there is a change in code and I want to re-test it (In App purchase thing), but since the feature is already bought I cannot test it again.

I am running and testing the application from Xcode, so I tried to delete the application from device and run / test it again by from Xcode, still no result.

Comment: Pratik, I have the exact problem as you described -- how do you "unpurchase" an item or reset a test account. Adding new sandbox users will become extremely tedious. Can you please let me know what you came up with? Thanks!

Comment: I ran into this problem as well, it seems quite odd that there is no way to reset the state of a Test Users purchases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to test re-downloading the content, deleting the application works.

If you want to actually re-buy it, how about creating a new additional sandbox account?