# How to Re-buy when testing InApp Purchase with Sandbox?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ipad, ios-4.2, storekit

I have already visited this thread

[iPhone + In App purchase testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175173/iphone-in-app-purchase-testing)

but the solution of creating a new account each time you want to buy the same item is extremly tedious.

There is also the solution of creating a new product or I guess by changing the product identifier should work too but this is not a very friendly and productive solution as well.

So, is there any documented way of un-purchasing and than purchasing again a product when testing InApp purchase with sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to un-purchase your items, as re-buying them on the same account really gives you the very same transaction, minus the money.

There is no way of doing this, other than creating new users.